# Synthetic geometry theorems that relate lengths to areas

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, math-history, axiomatic-geometry

Does anyone know any synthetic geometry theorems (so, no algebra at all) or sources with synthetic geometry theorems, that relate lengths to areas? My only reference currently is Euclid's Elements, and I was hoping I could find other theorems. It doesn't matter if it's very old.

If this is of interest of anyone, here are the ones I found in Euclid's Elements:

B1 P42: Generate a parallelogram equal in area to a given triangle.

B1 P45: Find a parallelogram equal in area to a given polygon

B1 P47: the pythagorean theorem

B2 P14: Find a square equal to any given polygon

B6 P1: areas of triangles and parallelograms of the same height are proportional to their bases.

B6 P16: rectangles of equal area have proportional sides

B12 P2: areas of circles are proportional to the squares on their diameters

Comment: A major reference is [Cauchy-Crofton's theorem](https://math.osu.edu/sites/math.osu.edu/files/What%20is%202017%20Croftons%20Formula.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for the reference!

Comment: How about using [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Area_calculation) for area calculation, by means of a line integral ? But I suppose that's not enough _synthetic geometry_ :-(

Comment: @HandeBruijn thank you for the reference! Right, I'm looking mostly for theorems (and most of all, sources other than Euclid) that use no algebra, but I'll keep this one too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this list may be of help.

1. *Greenberg, Marvin Jay*, Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries. Development and history, New York, NY: W. H. Freeman and Company (ISBN 978-0-7167-9948-1). xxix, 637 p. (2008). [ZBL1127.51001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1127.51001).
2. *Boyer, Carl B.*, History of analytic geometry, Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 0-486-43832-5). x, 291 p. (2004). [ZBL1099.51002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1099.51002).
3. *Mlodinow, Leonard*, Euclid’s window. The story of geometry from parallel lines to hyperspace, New York, NY: Free Press. xii, 306 p. (2001). [ZBL0990.01001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0990.01001).\
4. *Halsted, G. B.*, [**Synthetic projective geometry. ((2^{\text{nd}}) edition).**](http://resolver.library.cornell.edu/math/1803562), New York: Wiley. 37 S. (8^\circ). [Mathematical monographs edited by M. Merriman aiid R. S. Woodward. Nr. 2.] (1906). [ZBL37.0563.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:37.0563.03).